# Asking questions in a language other than English

Tags: support, languages

I know there are some topics about it but I didn't find the the answered of my question.

Imagine I want to ask an extremely precise question with a lot shades in one of all possible subjects on Stack Exchange but I am not fluent in English.  Can I find someone here to help me to translate my question?

Comment: Do you mean asking a question on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/), or some other Stack Exchange site? I ask because by and large Stack Exchange sites are English-language only (except for a couple language-specific versions of StackOverflow, and a few language usage site), while here we've been [somewhat more welcoming to questions posted in another language](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1617/8348).

Comment: Follow Pedro's advice. This has been successfully done at least a couple of times. I recall friendly users having given translations from German, French, Spanish and Portuguese at least. Do try to give an English translation. That may speed up things, because some of us are very good at guessing what is actually meant. There are hotheads who start shooting at such questions, but ignore them. Asking bilingually is IMO most likely to succeed. Then it will be clear to all that some of the illogical parts of the question may be errors in translation.

Comment: Yes for exemple

Comment: And use [translation-request](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-request) as an additional tag. That is mostly used by people trouble with a paragraph or two in a published paper, but I don't see why it wouldn't work here as well.

Comment: See the new FAQ: [What is Math SE's policy on posts in languages other than English?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35656)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. Write your post in your preferred language, and include a disclaimer (preferably in English) that asks for a translation. You can link to this post so that people know this practice is something we encourage.

Comment: OK thank you very much ! :)

Comment: Is this to be considered an official policy, or is it your view as an individual moderator? I'm considering suggesting something like this on another SE, and if I do, I'd include a link here, but only if it's an official policy.

Comment: @SixthOfFour This appears to be an acceptable practice on [math.se], which may or may not be acceptable elsewhere. There is a more official-looking [FAQ post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/259867) on [meta.se], which however is more applicable to the sites it directly mentions than to the entire network (see the comments under the question). In practice, this matter is dealt with on site level.

Comment: @Fundamental I understand all that. What I meant by "official policy" was official policy on [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/), and my reason for wanting to link to this, is that if I can show that it's been adopted as policy here, it may be easier to get positive responses to such a suggestion on another site within the network.

Comment: If MSE does not have a strict “English only” policy then I would suggest that information to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/196432